# How to check user password in angular's strongloop SDK?

Tags: angularjs, strongloop

I want to check the current user's password in order to allow him to change his/her password.

According to the user model docs, the way to do this is using the user.hasPassword method, by I get a "is not a function" error. 
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/User#user-prototype-haspassword

There is no reference to this in the angular SDK docs, so I'm guessing this method is not avalable from angular. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK#AngularJSJavaScriptSDK-Authentication

Any clues on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is just semantics, but if you are using the built in User model, you don't ever "check a user's password," you check if they are authenticated with a valid authToken that is set in a header.

But if you are trying to change a user's password and requiring them to *log in before changing it*, you can also just call User.login() and verify that you get a success response from the API. Then use the new password and persist it by updating the User instance with an update or updateAttributes.

See https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-sdk-angular/#user

Will look something like this (warning: quick writeup, not tested!):

```
User.login({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.oldPassword}, function(response){

  // user login was valid, now update user with new password by user id
  //
  User.prototype$updateAttributes({id: response.user.id}, {password: $scope.newPassword}, 
  function(response) {
    // success
  }, function(response) {
    // fail
  });

}, function(response) {
  // login failed, send to login screen
});
```